# AlertDialog message with new line. (\n doesn't work.)

Tags: android, dialog, line-breaks

I need to use a break-line in a `AlertDialog` on Android.
I already tried with the "\n" character but it doesn't work. I don't see the "\n" character but the text wont wrap.

Any help?

Comment: That should have done it. The \n works perfectly fine

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spanned text using `Html.fromHtml("some string" + "<br>")` to create new line on some textview element.

Comment: Html.fromHtml("<br>") does nothing else than build the charsequence "\n".

Answer (score 3):

If you are receiving the String from somewhere, maybe the `\n` is being escaped.

Try with:

```
string = string.replace("\\n","\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the HTML tag to set new text?

```
    controlName.setText(Html.fromHtml(outputString + "<br/>" + outputString2));
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter when use "\n" in Dialog or Activity/Fragment.
I faced the same issue but it turned out the TextView have the attribute:     **android:singleLine="true"** or **android:maxLines="1"**, it conflicts with "\n" so make sure to REMOVE these attributes first.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a string in your strings.xml with a `\n` line break like

```
<string name="line_break_string">Hello\nWorld</string>
```

You can use

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setMessage(R.string.line_break_string)
    .show()
```

and the line break will be respected.