# \n does not generate newline in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, escaping, android-alertdialog

I am reading strings taken from an XML file (via a PullParser) into an AlertDialog. I need to be able to display multi-line text in the AlertDialog. The normal recommendation ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511261/displaying-multiple-lines-of-text-in-an-alert-dialog) for example) is to use \n to represent newline. [Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166315/alertdialog-message-with-new-line-n-dont-work) says that that "should have worked". Well, it didn't.

Here's the code for the AlertDialog, where completionString is the string taken from the XML:

```
public void gameComplete()
{
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    myTimer.cancel();
    myTimer = null;

    alert.setMessage(completionString);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            finish();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

But here's what the actual screenshot looks like:

[image]

Whether I use one or two slashes in the string (\n or \\n) in the string, the AlertDialog takes it literally and just prints those exact characters, not a new line. How do I get it to show an actual new line?

In case the problem is with the pull parser, here's the code that pulls this string from the XML file and into the completionString variable:

```
private void parseXml()
{
    // Post1: tuningVars contains the values in the XML tuning file corresponding to the difficulty settings for this particular game.
    // Post2: completion, win, bonus, fail strings are filled out from the endgamestrings.xml file,
    // matching the digit specified by the QR/input code.
    XmlPullParser theParser = Xml.newPullParser();

    try {
        // Post1

        // Specify the XML file to be parsed.
        InputStream theStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("tuning.xml");
        theParser.setInput(theStream, null);

        // Parse!
        int eventType = theParser.getEventType();
        String gameTitle = "";
        String tagName;
        int[] difficultyNums = new int[5];

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                tagName = theParser.getName();
                Log.i("XML Parser", "Got a tag called " + tagName);

                if (tagName.equals("game")) {
                    gameTitle = theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "title");
                    Log.i("XML Parser", "Found a game title tag " + gameTitle + " and this game is " + extras.getString(GAME_NAME));
                }

                if (gameTitle.equals(extras.getString(GAME_NAME))) {
                    Log.i("XML Parser", "Adding variables for " + gameTitle);

                    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                        String nextTagName = "";

                        if (theParser.getName() != null) {
                            nextTagName = theParser.getName();
                        }
                        Log.i("XML Parser", "Next tag name is" + nextTagName);
                        if (nextTagName.equals("gamevar")) {
                            String varName = theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "varname");
                            difficultyNums[0] = Integer.parseInt(theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "easyval"));
                            difficultyNums[1] = Integer.parseInt(theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "mediumval"));
                            difficultyNums[2] = Integer.parseInt(theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "hardval"));
                            difficultyNums[3] = Integer.parseInt(theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "hackerinc"));
                            difficultyNums[4] = Integer.parseInt(theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "languageinc"));

                            // then construct the Tuning variable and add it to the array
                            TuningVariable varToAdd = new TuningVariable(varName, difficultyNums);
                            tuningVars.add(varToAdd);
                            Log.i("XML Parser", "Added tuning variable " + varName);
                        }

                        eventType = theParser.next();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("XML Parser", "I compared " + extras.getString(GAME_NAME) + " with " + gameTitle + " and decided they were not the same.");
                }
            }
            eventType = theParser.next();
        }

        // Post2

        // Specify the XML file to be parsed.
        theStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("endgamestrings.xml");
        theParser.setInput(theStream, null);

        int chosenDigit = extras.getInt(STRINGS_NUM);

        Log.i("XML Parser", "Running PullParser on endgamestrings.");

        // Parse!
        eventType = theParser.getEventType();
        int stringNum = -1;
        String parsedGameType;
        String selectedGameType;

        // Define which games are accelerators and which puzzles.
        // It would probably make more sense to do this via the XML as well, but let's start here for testing.
        switch (extras.getString((GAME_NAME))) {
            case "Simon":
                selectedGameType = "accelerator";
                break;
            case "Square":
                selectedGameType = "accelerator";
                break;
            case "Pegs":
                selectedGameType = "puzzle";
                break;
            case "Pipes":
                selectedGameType = "puzzle";
                break;
            case "Lights":
                selectedGameType = "puzzle";
        }


        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            // Log.i("XML Parser", "Running PullParser while loop on endgamestrings.");

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                tagName = theParser.getName();
                // Log.i("XML Parser", "Got a tag called " + tagName);

                if (tagName.equals("setofstrings"))
                {
                    stringNum = Integer.parseInt(theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                    parsedGameType = theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "type");
                }

                if (stringNum == chosenDigit)
                {
                    /*
                    // Java is whining like a bitch about these variables not being initialized.
                    // Won't bother with this particular error-catching for now.
                    if (parsedGameType.equals("puzzle") && selectedGameType.equals("accelerator"))
                    {
                        String warning = "Warning: Accelerator strings passed to puzzle. Setting strings to default.";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, warning, 10);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                    */

                    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                    {
                        String nextTagName = "";
                        String stringType = "";

                        if (theParser.getName() != null)
                        {
                            nextTagName = theParser.getName();
                        }

                        if (nextTagName.equals("string"))
                        {
                            stringType = theParser.getAttributeValue(null, "type");
                            Log.i("XML Parser", "Found a string type tag " + stringType);
                        }

                        switch (stringType)
                        {
                            case ("time"):
                                completionString = theParser.nextText();
                                break;
                            case ("bonus"):
                                bonusString = theParser.nextText();
                                break;
                            case ("win"):
                                winString = theParser.nextText();
                                break;
                            case ("fail"):
                                failString = theParser.nextText();
                                break;
                        }

                        eventType = theParser.next();
                    }
                }
            }
            eventType = theParser.next();
        }
    }
    catch (XmlPullParserException e)
    {
        Log.e("XML Parser", "Dude! XmlPullParserException!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("XML Parser", "Dude! IOException!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert.setMessage(completionString.replace("\\n", "\n"));
```